# Changing the variable against which a function is plotted in TikZ/PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I'm trying to graph a contour map of the function `r=-0.5(x^2+y^2)`, but with the axes as `y, 1-x`. What I wrote is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90}, xlabel=$1-x$, ylabel=$y$]
        \addplot3[
            domain=0:1, domain y=0:1, contour gnuplot={number=8},
        ] {-0.5((1-x)^2+y^2)};
        \addplot+[domain=0:1, domain y=0:1, no marks]({0.3}, {x});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Essentially inverting it to `r=-0.5((1-x)^2 + y^2)`. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this for more complicated functions?

Side note: I'm wondering if there is any better way to control the contours that are drawn besides just the `number=` option, i.e. display specific values of the `r` function?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  This is mostly a very well-asked question; but please consider wrapping your problem code with enough code to allow us to just copy-paste and compile it.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii Thanks, edited and hopefully added enough?

Comment: Almost.  ;-)  I just added the missing bits.  You need a `\documentclass` and `\begin`/`\end{document}` for it to be compilable.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii oh yeah, my bad! Either way, do you know how I could change the axis to be evaluated as `1-x`?

Comment: You can use `declare function` for the case of more complicated functions. Unfortunately, your code does not run through on my udated TeXLive2019 installation.